# How to auto run a code when user press Ctrl + C on cmd windows?

Tags: node.js, cmd

Currently I am working with npm scripts, so when user runs `npm start`, it shows a list of logs and everything. Now as soon as user presses Ctrl+c to exit, I want to auto-run some command like `clear` to clear whole terminal screen, How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look in this documentation https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_sigint.

Basically you will use the `readline` module - it provides an interface for reading data from a Readable stream (such as `process.stdin`) one line at a time. In your case, you want to get the 'SIGINT' event: it is emitted whenever the input stream receives a `Ctrl+C` input, known typically as SIGINT. If there are no 'SIGINT' event listeners registered when the input stream receives a SIGINT, the 'pause' event will be emitted.

```
import * as readline from 'node:readline/promises';
import { stdin as input, stdout as output } from 'node:process';

const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output });

rl.on('SIGINT', () => {
  rl.question('Are you sure you want to exit? ', (answer) => {
    if (answer.match(/^y(es)?$/i)) rl.pause();
  });
});
```

obs.: I did this just reading documentation, never actually implementing, but i think the answer is something like that.

Comment: Thanks it worked for capturing Ctrl +C event, and I searched doc for executing  shell commands !!